# do not process rule to htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

what is the rule for htaccess that makes all files text ?

like .php .py .pl whatever will be no different than .txt, source code should appear on the screen without execution.

thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ForceType text/plain`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#forcetype

Answer (score 1):

Create a rule in an .htaccess file in whatever directory you want to house your code examples.  The .htaccess file should have this in it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source php
```

That's it.  You'll get nice color coding.  Jeff's answer works well for all file types.